# Crystal report display data in a row

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

I have a set of records in the crystal report where I had included an image in the detail section. I need to suppress the image for example first record the image is displayed second it hides and again 3rd it displays and it goes on. The image which I have included in the detail section is this. Please help me on this

[image]

It should be displayed as below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Suppress expression for the image, use:

```
Remainder(RecordNumber, 2) = 0
```

Instead of using an image, you can simply use the color expression for the Detail section:

```
IF Remainder(RecordNumber, 2) = 0 Then crNoColor ELSE RGB(230,230,230)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I used the second code. I need to color inside the box only but it shows the entire details section. Could you help me on this?